# Get a variable out of socket.on

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have tried now to get a variable out of a `socket.on();` but can't get it out as it says it is an undefined variable.

Here is the code bit that doesn't work:

```
 io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.join("0");
    socket.on("chatroom",function(chat){
        socket.join(chat);
        if(chat != "0"){
        console.log("A user joined chatroom: " + chat);
        }
        var chatroom = chat;
    });

}); 

var chatroom = chatroom;
```

As you see it is the variable above that get's a value of undefined even if it has a value of 2 in the io.on fuction. Any ideas how to get it out?

Excuse me for my noobish codes (only 3 days experience in node.js)

Comment: It sounds like you maybe need to read this: [How to return a value from an asynchronous operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323).  The structure of what you're trying to do is just wrong.  Async results must be consumed IN the async response, not elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think the external `chatroom` variable is eclipsed by the internal one. Try:

```
var chatroom;
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.join("0");
    socket.on("chatroom", function(chat) {
        socket.join(chat);
        if(chat != "0") {
            console.log("A user joined chatroom: " + chat);
        }
        chatroom = chat;
    });    
});
```

Also, you have to understand, that because the code is asynchronous, the last line of your code will be executed before the code inside of the `io.on('connection', ...)`

Comment: Oh okay I understand but how do I make it execute before it executes the rest?

Comment: I also got an error from that as it says the variable is undefined... Could it be the same issue as it executes the code asynchronous

Comment: I'm missing a context here.. what do you want to do with that `chatroom` variable? Variable on which line is undefined?

Comment: The value of variable chatroom gets undefined outside the socket.on even if it is 4 inside it

Comment: The `chatroom` variable will be defined after the `socket.on(...)` is executed. If you use it before that, it is undefined. Try inserting the `console.log(..)` statements to understand the order of execution.